# svn asking passphrase when logged in through ssh, but not when working local

Tags: svn

I get a request for passphrase when I try to commit in svn (protocol svn+ssh) when connected remotely via ssh. If I do the same while locally connected, with a normal terminal session, I don't get this request. I have MacOSX 10.6.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

This is the standard behaviour of ssh. If you want it to not ask, you have to configure your ssh keys. I've written a post about it a while ago, i think it will help you :

http://www.codercaste.com/2009/10/07/how-to-setup-your-ssh-keys-for-authentication/

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. I think the problem is that command-line svn is behaving differently in shell session which are local (through Terminal.app) and remote (through ssh in from another machine). Which is weird.

Comment: Maybe you have checked out your local svn using "file:///" ? Whatever the case, to remotely connect without providing a key, you need to create ssh keys.

Comment: I already have the keys, and I didn't set up any passphrase for them. I normally connect to the ssh server without any request simply because I never set up a passphrase. This is the reason why it's very strange. I'm not even checking out. I am committing from an already checked out tree, hence all the info about the svn server are already on my machine. The only difference is that I am operating through ssh on my work machine, instead of being physically in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess there's some different in the scripts being run when the shell starts. Does Terminal run a login shell? Does ssh? If they're different, then one will run .bash_profile and the other won't. IMHO, all interactive shells should be login shells, but it's common for graphical terminals not to be. ssh should always start a login shell.

As a method of diagnosis, try running `set` in both a local and an ssh shell, and comparing the output; if they're different, that points to a different set of scripts having run.

Comment: bash_profile does not contain anything special. I can't really see any reason which could trigger this behavior, either directly or indirectly

Comment: Any differences in the output of `set`?